# Jacobian of function from $\mathbb R^{2n} \to \mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, jacobian

I have a problem that's insisting that I formulate a function $f(\vec x) \to \vec y$, where $\vec x \in \mathbb R^{2n}$ and $\vec y \in \mathbb C^n$.

When I take the Jacobian of $f$, I end up with a $2n \times n$ matrix of complex numbers.  This is distressing, because I'm doing an optimization problem that really "wants" a full-rank Jacobian.  On the other hand, each complex number carries *two* real ones, so there's got to be a full rank matrix in there somehow.

Based on the way the problem is structured, I'm pretty sure that I can declare a "real valued" Jacobian $J_r = \begin{bmatrix}\mathcal Re{\nabla f(x)} \\ \mathcal Im{\nabla f(x)}\end{bmatrix}$ and then use it as if it were arrived at by perfectly normal means.

Is there a way to treat this that's either more theoretically robust, more compact, or both?  Or am I already doing this correctly, and this is the best I get?

Comment: You can forget the complex structure and identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. That gets you a $2n \times 2n$ matrix of real numbers (basically separating out your $2n \times n$ matrix of complex numbers into real and imaginary components).

Comment: I guess a large part of my question is -- yes, but is that _all_?  It'll work, but it certainly lacks elegance.

Comment: Why? I don't know what you want a "full-rank" (I assume you mean invertible) Jacobian for but this is how you get it and it's straightforward.

Comment: It's for optimization using Newton's method or similar.  And yes, I mean invertible.

Comment: @TimWescott Newton's method for optimization doesn't require an invertible Jacobian. I'd suggest you add context for what you actually want to do in order to avoid [xy-problems](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Well, really I want compact, pretty notation, because I'm going to be doing a lot of this.  I did forget my basics on multidimensional Newton's method.